# Can you put a sauna heater for a higher cubic footage in a smaller room?

Tags: electrical

I am wanting to build a sauna in my master closet. The room is 250 cubic feet. The two sauna heaters I'm considering are a 6kW unit and a 9kW unit. The 6kW unit is for rooms 160-275 cubic feet, and the 9kW unit is for rooms 290-400 cubic feet. Since my room is very close to the upper boundary in size for the 6kW unit, I'm considering sizing up. To be safe, I ran an 8-wire to the closet, so I definitely am able to do either unit from an electrical perspective, but are there any other concerns that could arise from putting the 9kW unit in the slightly smaller room? The reason I'm considering sizing up is so the room heats faster. Will sizing up even accomplish that?

Comment: The basic answer is "Yes, that will work but it seems like a lot of heat for a very small room". The longer answer involves looking at the details. Make/model #? "8-wire" - does that mean 8 AWG? If so, how many wires or what type of cable?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact The unit I'm considering is a HIVE 9 sauna (https://www.steamsaunabath.com/54776/huum/hive-mini-9/electric-heaters) by HUUM. And yes, I do mean copper 8 AWG Romex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sizing up the heater will increase the speed at which the room heats up.

For furnaces, boilers, and heat pumps a common concern with a too-big unit is 'short cycling'. When a unit is oversized, it will run for too short of a period to work properly, lowering efficiency and potentially damaging the equipment.

With an electric resistance heater such this sauna heater, this over-sizing is not a concern. You could install a 20kW heater in this small room if your electrical service will support it. In fact, over-sizing like this is a common setup for all sorts of devices. Think of an electric cooktop as an example: you can set it to barely keep a burner warm, or to quickly boil water with several kW of power.

The most likely downside is a quicker wear-out of a mechanical thermostat. An electronic thermostat should suffer no downsides at all. Electronic thermostats that cycle the heat element several times a second to maintain very precise control exist.

One other factor to consider: make sure you've done an electrical load calculation. If the smaller heater fits in your electrical service but the bigger one does not, that could drive you to choose the smaller unit instead.

Comment: Thank you- this makes perfect sense. Can you help me understand what you mean by electrical load calculation? If I size up, the unit will draw 9 kW of power. Since it's a 240V outlet, it requires 9000/240 = 37.5 amps. The 8 awg copper wire should be able to handle up to 40 amps, and I have a 40 amp breaker installed. Does that mean everything is fine in terms of load?

Comment: For the individual circuit, sure, that sounds fine. It's the overall load on your panel that you need to think about. You will have to do a load calculation as part of your electrical permit for this work.

Comment: That makes full sense @KMJ . I'd like to add a steam shower and sauna to the house, and I already have a 35000 BTU garage heater for my shop and an EV charger, so likely this could end up being too much for a 200 amp box. I am trying to find literature online on how to upgrade this. I read about upgrading it to a 400 amp box, but do you think it's possible to install another 200 amp box, and route some stuff to one 200 amp box, and some to the other 200 amp box. I think this option could be cheaper, but let me know what you think. Thanks.

Comment: Make that a different question. Do the load calculation first, though. You might be fine. And don't sweat high amp EV charging, almost nobody needs more than a few kW of charging there. Our 16A 240V charger works great, for instance.

Comment: No need for the other question, I did the load calculations, and I should be fine. I just can't charge the EV while using both the sauna and steam shower... but that is a scenario I cannot even imagine. And it's certainly not worth paying thousands to upgrade a box for. I really appreciate all your input. I did have one question in follow up to your original answer, though. What did you mean by "quicker wear out of a mechanical thermostat?" How will a higher kW unit wear out a thermostat more quickly? Is it because it will have to adjust heat more often?

Comment: Mechanical thermostats, particularly ones that switch high power, only have so many cycles before the contacts wear out. With a big unit it will switch far more often and likely wear out quicker. Now, this could be 'in ten years' instead of 'in thirty years' but it's still a factor. Regarding the load calculation, did you follow the alternate method? Code doesn't usually allow for 'can't do these things at the same time' usage but your demand factors might effectively allow that anyway.

Comment: Got it - that makes sense about the mechanical vs electrical. As for the load calculation, all I did was make a list of everything that takes amps in my house and added them up. [Here are my calculations](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jr036smEFVyW-EwqPqAgEkqHBbwsgq5cJUgnD1U7Gbg/edit?usp=sharing). I couldn't find anything on the internet about the alternate method. How would I do that?

Comment: You don't just add everything up - there's a method specified in NEC 220.82. Hunt around here and you'll see examples. If you want to know more about this I again suggest opening a new question. Your method is not accurate.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I have posted a question [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/264559/could-someone-help-me-with-an-electrical-load-calculation-for-my-home). I'd appreciate any feedback there.