# Could someone help me with an electrical load calculation for my home?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am installing a lot of electric heavy equipment in my new home, and could use some help confirming I am up to all code standards and can safely run everything. I need a bit of help making sure I am doing everything correctly. I am using the method outlined [here](https://www.huntingtonbeachca.gov/files/users/building_and_safety/MethodLoadCalculation.pdf).

1. General Lighting and Receptacle Loads: 2300 sq ft * 3 = 6900
2. Small-Appliance Branch Circuits: 1500 x 3 = 4500. For this one, I have 3 GFI outlets in the kitchen, which is where I'm getting the number 3 from. I have another GFI in the master bath, so should I include it in the calculation (i.e. 1500 x 4 = 6000)?
3. Laundry Brach Circuit(s): 1500 x 2 = 3000. For this one, I am using two because I have a washer and a dryer. Is this correct?
4. Here is a table of what appliances I have:
   [image]
5. In the table above.
6. Air-Conditioning and cooling systems: 4500 x 100% = 4500 (I assume this is just my A/C) 
    Electric thermal storage: 100% x 800 = 800 (I assume this is just my gas furnace) 
    Supplemental electric heating equipment: 65% x 0 = 0 (I am not sure what this is... please advise).
7. 4500 + 36000 = 40500
8. 40500A / 240V ≈ 170A

My breaker box is rated for 200A, so does that mean I am fine with my electrical load? I am also unsure of what these results mean... does this mean I can run everything at once and nothing will trip the breaker? I am confused because simply adding all the amperage, I have ~340A total in use:

[image]

Is there a reason why my calculations yield so much lower than just adding them up?

I appreciate any help/suggestions with my calculations and determining if installing this all is safe/up to code and that I'll actually be able to run everything.

For reference, here is a picture of my breaker:

[image]

Comment: Most panels if you add up the breaker sizes will add up to close to double the panel size.  Most circuits using 15/20 amp breakers only use an amp or two most of the time.  About the time you use most of the breaker size is when using electric heating elements(toaster, kettle, hair dryer).  For your branch circuits, are you using the number of outlets or the number of separate circuits?  One branch circuit can(and most do) a number of outlets, so for branch circuits count the number of breakers.

Comment: Got it. For branch circuits, I was a little confused and just used the number of GFI outlets I had in the kitchen. I had 3 GFI's, each on a separate breaker, which is why I used 3. I have 26 items on my breaker, so should I just use 26 for number of branch circuits?

Comment: Noooo. Count breakers for an area. I bet there's two for your kitchen if it was recently wired.

Comment: My kitchen area in general has one for the fridge, another two for GFI outlets, a fourth for a GFI outlet in the island, a fifth for the lights, a sixth for the microwave, and a seventh for the garbage disposal. So a total of 7 in the kitchen. Oddly enough, I do not see one for the dishwasher or range. For reference, I've updated the question with a picture of my breaker box.

Comment: If each of the three GFCI outlets are on separate breakers then use 3(one on each breaker)  Will need to see which outlets are on which breaker.  Dishwasher and range/stove  probably on their own breakers.  To find out which outlets are on which breakers, turn off the breaker and see which outlets still work.

Comment: A *lot* of things need adjustments here. For example, your microwave @ 1700W only gets used for a few minutes at a time - if it is a countertop microwave then it gets counted already as part of a kitchen circuit. If it is a built-in then there is a complicated (relatively) calculation for the oven which would probably include it. "GFCI" is nothing magic for load calculations - irrelevant. (GFCIs are **important** but have nothing to do with load calc.) Heat and A/C normally you just count the larger one since they don't run at the same time. Tesla 11520 - that's 48A of charging, which is a

Comment: **lot** you could lower that (just change the configuration) if you are getting close to total limits. Fridge 1800W - I'm dubious about that - a modern fridge should only use a small fraction of that. Steam shower - that's a lot, don't know if load calculations allow for adjustment because it is only used for short periods of time but they might.

Comment: I tried to overestimate everything just to make sure I'm certainly not over limits. From what you said, though, I think I am fine, since the steam shower, microwave, etc will only be used for short periods of time.

Comment: Also, go read the code sections mentioned in the form you linked. They will help illuminate some of the assumptions that go in to a load calculation. If you have Excel there's a 2017 version of the calculation spreadsheet available at https://www.naperville.il.us/projects-in-naperville/residential-load-calculation-worksheet/ to make it a little easier to see how your assumptions change the calculation in real time.

Comment: You do not run the AC and heating at same time, so do not add them

Comment: **This might help** https://ask-the-electrician.com/residential-electrical-load-calculation.html#beginAdv

Comment: Thank you @Ruskes, it does. Much easier than doing the calculations by hand and making so many mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Small-Appliance Branch Circuits: 1500 x 3 = 4500.

That is correct for a whole house but...

> For this one, I have 3 GFI outlets in the kitchen, which is where I'm getting the number 3 from. I have another GFI in the master bath, so should I include it in the calculation (i.e. 1500 x 4 = 6000)?

No, you don't apply 1500 VA per receptacle... correct is 1500 VA *per circuit* i.e. breaker.  So if you have two 20A kitchen circuits, which is the slumlord bare minimum, then 2x1500VA = 3000 VA.

> Laundry Brach Circuit(s): 1500 x 2 = 3000. For this one, I am using two because I have a washer and a dryer. Is this correct?

No, same issue, 1 circuit 1 breaker 1 allocation of 1500 VA.

Also, washer and dryer are accounted for in that 1500 VA and you don't need a separate allocation unless the dryer is electric.

> Fridge 1800 VA

I seriously doubt that.  Common basic fridges are 90-120W *while they are running*.   I would fact-check that info by plugging it into a Kill-a-Watt.

> Heater 10,000 VA

Wait, what? Is that a garage heater or something?

You take the max of all your heating loads, and the max of all your A/C loads, and pick the larger number.  You won't be heating the garage while running the A/C.

Do yourself a favor, dump the resistive heating and get an extended range heat pump instead.  That won't cost a dollar an hour to run!

> Supplemental electric heating equipment: 65% x 0 = 0 (I am not sure what this is... please advise).

Probably means that 10,000W garage heater.  But also emergency heat for older heat pumps.

> Tesla charger 11520 VA

OK [stop right there and watch this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w&t=1695s). Thinking you need a 60A circuit for EV charging is just lemming behavior we see a lot from novice EVers.  That kind of speed is not appropriate for a home, it makes sense for "Destination Chargers" at hotels where someone typically plans their travel to arrive at the hotel at 7% charge and let the hotel pay for a complete fill-up.   You will typically get home with only 5-100 miles removed that day, and you'll have all night to charge, you don't need to finish in 5-100 minutes!  15-20A at 240V (2880-3840 VA) will cover just about everybody, and you can always supplement it with Supercharging for that "But Sometimes" moment you're about to argue.

And yes, you can set the same Wall Connector for any charge rate from 15-60A.

I mean hey, if you wanna, it's not like there's a punishment for putting that big a charger in.  But don't go spending a bunch of money on 400A service out of thinking it's *necessary*.   If you need to de-tune the EVSE to make it fit in 200A, don't be bashful about doing so.

For that matter it doesn't even need to be a dedicated circuit. No limit to the number of receptacles on a general-purpose 30A circuit, so one circuit could serve dryer and plug-in EVSE, and both appliances are covered in 5760 VA on the Load Calc.

> Bedrooms and hallway 1.86667

No no, those aren't broken out separately, those are covered in the "catch-all" of 3 VA per square foot.

Comment: Thank you so much for the amazing insights. I really appreciate it. The reason I allocated so much amps for the Tesla charger is that I had remaining 6 wire left from running the steam shower and sauna wires, so I thought why not max it out. You can regulate how many amps Teslas draw directly from the vehicle, so I doubt I'll ever use more than 20 to preserve the battery. This calculation is more meant for me as a worst case scenario for me.

Comment: As for the garage heater, I only plan on using it for one or two hours a day in the wintertime. You said it correctly, it uses 10kW/hr  at max strength, so at $0.10/kWh, it won't be more than $1/hr, aka at most $60/month extra in the wintertime. What kind of heat pump would heat up the garage? And adding duct work would be significantly expensive.

Comment: @Manny I am no expert but I believe you're allowed to use bigger wire on a smaller circuit if you want to. You can make it a 20 amp circuit with really thick wire. However you might need special splices to connect the thick wire to the normal size breakers and receptacles. Again, I'm no expert so wait for someone like Harper to chime in.

Comment: @Manny #6 NM-B cable is only 55A.  The Tesla Wall Connector doesn't have a 55A setting *for some reason, did no one ever read NEC 310.15(B)(16)? There is no such thing as 60A wire*... so you must use the 50A setting.  On heat pumps, in shops/garages most people go for "mini-split" units that only require a 2" hole in the wall to pass the lineset through. Hit Youtube you'll find a lot of people doing it for their garage/shops, using models designed for DIY.  They do not require handling of freon.